# can we run java on my machine pointing to the other machine's JAVA Path?

Tags: java, jvm

It could be basic java question. can we run java on my machine pointing to the other machine's JAVA Path?
Example: I have a test.class file in my machine (system-A). But my machine does not have java(no JDK or No JRE). Shall I run this test.class by using other system's java path?

Comment: You are missing a whole lot of detail here. How is "system-A" going to be able to magically use another physical system's Java installation?

Comment: You mean we can not run any java file (or program) from my machine (where no java is available) pointing to the other system (where java is installed).

Comment: This is borderline off topic for SO, I think. It's really more of a general computing question (which might be more on topic at http://superuser.com) -- "how can I run a program from one machine, where the program's executable (and supporting libraries, etc) is located on another machine?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not need to be "installed" to function correctly. At least not the core Java, though some tools of Java may need extra setup.

If your machine can see a Java home directory on a network share, you can simply run `java.exe` directly from that share.

Example: If you have access to a network share like `\\Server1\Software` and it has a Java installed in directory `Java\jdk1.8.0_65`, then you can run your code like this:

```
\\Server1\Software\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java.exe -cp . test
```

This of course assumes that `test.class` exists in the current working directory, and that the class is in the unnamed package.

Using the above will work, even without setting up `JAVA_HOME` or `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: You mean to say we can run java program (simple one, lets say just sysout statement) by pointing to other system's java path (shared system, it could be other server or other system, where we can access the java installed location)?

Answer (score 1):

No, you must have access to a java executable to run java.  The original post states that there is no java runtime environment on the computer.
If, however, you have access to `java.exe` then you can execute that `java.exe`

Comment: FYI: You don't actually have to set any environment variables to run Java, it doesn't even have to be on the path.

Comment: I've updated appropriately after testing. Good on you!